# How to solve inter-dependency of the composed class on it's property

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

In one of the project I am working on, I am facing a problem in terms of creating an object with a dependency that sits at a deeper level in the class composition. Following diagram shows the class composition.

[image: Class Diagram]

The problem I am facing is as follows:

1. The IFrameGrid object contains 'IBracings' object at a deeper level in the class composition.
2. Creation of the object 'IBracings' requires 'INodeEnvelope' which is a struct consisting of 4 Node (a geometric Point) objects.
3. IFrameGrid requires the IBracings to be instantiated as soon as the UI is displayed to the user so that the user can change IBracings type based on the need. However, for IBracings to be instantiated the IFrameGrid should have been instantiated already since the INodeEnvelope is dependent on the root level user input.

UI looks something like this:

[image: Typical UI]

I have a feeling that, this is a design problem and I could not figure out as to what changes should be made to resolve this issue and honestly I am not a software developer.

I hope the description and the images above gives a fair understanding to convey my issue.

I tried to refactor this by introducing some AbstractFactories but no success as the ConcreteFactory implementation for creating the IBracings has a dependency on INodeEnvelope which can be acquired only after IFrameGrid object is available which itself has an indirect dependency on IBracings.

I also tried to find a solution in the web. Unfortunately I could not find anything relevant.

Can someone help me in identifying and resolving this and is much appreciated if it is elaborated.

PS: The title may not be apt for the question I am posting and I am not sure about what other title could be apt.

**Update 1:**

Removed IBraceDefinition to reduce the complexity. Now the abstract base class Frame stores the properties Pattern and Bracings directly.

[image]

Comment: *"for IBracings to be instantiated the IFrameGrid should have been instantiated already since the INodeEnvelope is dependent on the root level user input"* - I have no idea what that sentence means.

Comment: IBracings is a property deep inside the IFrameGrid class which depends on INodeEnvelope (a struct with four Node objects).
The four nodes of INodeEnvelope can only be created based on the properties of IFrameGrid i.e., the Spacing, Width and Height.

Now the issue is:
IBracings should be instantiated with a valid INodeEnvelope at the time of instantiation of IFrameGrid so that user can interact. But the data in IFrameGrid will be provided by user after the instantiation of IFrameGrid which changes INodeEnvelope. Thought of using an event but it only is making it complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds complex. If I understand it right your problem is that you can't set the properties on a child object without user input to populate the parent?

Surely the simple answer is to set them to null and populate dynamically as the user fills in the data?

I would categorise this as an "unfilled form" type problem. Where your data structure is designed to only work for valid data. ie a bridge of type X with whatever bracings. But your form has to be displayed with invalid data. ie type not chosen, width of span not populated etc.

I know there is a principle where people say you shouldn't allow invalid data or objects to exist. However, I find this to be untrue. An empty form is a one example, but you also have to consider changes to rule sets over time which might invalidate old data etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, the understanding is correct that the Child object (the Bracings cannot be instantiated without the input from user.
I tried setting the Bracings object to null so as to let the user fill the required information but the problem is creeping-in in two different forms:
a. When the Bracings object is set to null -> The UI is not populating the relevant options for IBracingDefintion and is not getting updated after the input is provided.
b. When data of IFrameGrid is changed at some point later, the condition is back to square one.

Comment: you will need to program the UI to deal with nulls. it sounds like you are missing a viewmodel layer between the model and UI?

Comment: I am making a few modifications in the design and starting with nulls as recommended. I could see some light but I think it requires some restructuring of my main class 'Bridge'. Let me see if can reach to a solution after the restructuring.

BTW: I am using the MVVM architecture and the application is created using WPF (C#). I do have a ViewModel to handle the interaction of the user with UI and the underlying models.

Comment: AHh ok, yes i can see it would be a problem binding directly to a VM where you potentially have nulls, or switch out the classes in WCF. I think you will need some extra IsPopulated, BridgeType, BracingType etc properties on your view model and conditional rendering of sections based on those properties

Comment: Yes the application has BridgeType, GridType and BracingPattern enums which are used to impart the polymorphic behaviour. I presume that I may need to use some events too (probably in IFrameGrid - I am afraid that it may be a 'static' one) so that updates can be triggered accordingly.